# Loop through columns in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to add a number to all columns in a DataFrame. I am trying to use,

```
for i in names(df)
    df.i = df.i .+ 1
end
```

But this is giving error as `ArgumentError: column name :i not found in the data frame`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Current advice for DataFrames.jl 1.0 or newer

Just write:

```
df .+= 1
```

to get what you want.

If you want to loop through columns it is also supported. Here are some examples:

```
for n in names(df)
    df[!, n] .+= 1
end

for col in eachcol(df)
    col .+= 1
end
```

#### Old advice for DataFrames.jl before 1.0 release

Currently you can use:

```
for i in axes(df, 2)
    df[i] .+= 1
end
```

or

```
for n in names(df)
    df[n] .+= 1
end
```

However, in the future you might need to write (there is a discussion if we should change the meaning of single argument indexing):

```
for col in eachcol(df, false)
    col .+= 1
end
```

or

```
foreach(x -> x .+= 1, eachcol(df, false))
```

Comment: Is there any update on this? I am trying to generate new columns like the following but getting similar errors
```
for i = 1:n
    df.x_$i .= (df.x$i .- df.x$(i - 1)) ./ df.x_$i
end
```

Comment: Yes - the advice was for DataFrames.jl before its 1.0 release. I added the current way to write this (and this will not change in the future).

Comment: Thanks Bogumil. My question was slightly different, in the sense, I am trying to create columns using an iteration. The objective is to create columns x_1, x_2 and x_3, which are functions of (x_0, x_1), (x_1, x_2) and (x_2, x_3) respectively. This is what I was trying to achieve with the loop in the above comment. Unfortunately not iterating it in a loop and instead explicitly defining each it is not a great option, because this is part of a function which takes as one of the arguments, the set of columns to be created.

Comment: Your code should be ``` for i = 1:n df[!, "x_$i"] = (df[!, "x$i"] .- df[!, "x$(i - 1)"]) ./ df[!, "x_$i"] end ```.